# add checkbox to Excel UserForm at design time using vba

Tags: excel, checkbox, userform, design-time, vba

When I try to add checkboxes to a UserForm in Excel at design time using the following VBA code I get:

> "Run time error '13': Type Mismatch"`

At the statement `Set cb = UFvbc.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1")`.

```
Sub Add4Controls()
   Dim UFvbc As VBComponent
   Dim r As Long

   Set UFvbc = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1")

   'Add 4 CheckBoxes
   Dim cb As CheckBox 
   For r = 1 To 4
      Set cb = UFvbc.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1")
      With cb
        (some statements to set .Width, .Height, .Left, .Top, and .Caption)
      End With
   Next r
End Sub
```

But if I change:

`Dim cb As CheckBox` to 
 
`Dim cb As CommandButton`

And

`Set cb = UFvbc.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms. CheckBox.1")` to 
`Set cb = UFvbc.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms. CommandButton.1")`

Then I get 4 CommandButtons in a column as expected. Although `cb` is `“False”`, which was unexpected.

I can get the checkboxes by dropping “As CheckBox” from the declaration for `cb` and making it Variant, but it irritates me that I need to do that (and I’ll never admit how long it took me to discover that), and I don’t understand why it works with `CommandBar` but not `Checkbox`. What is it that I don’t understand?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of your code adding 4 checkboxes:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Add4Controls()
    'Microsoft Visual Basic Applications Extensibility 5.3
    Dim UFvbc As VBComponent
    Dim r As Long

    Set UFvbc = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1")
    Dim cb As Control
    For r = 7 To 10
        Set cb = UFvbc.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox" & r, True)
        With cb
            Debug.Print cb.Name
        End With
    Next r    
End Sub
```

As a side note - whenever you are using external library, as in this case, make sure that you mention it.